# How to run (if possible) gpu-accelerated apps in LXC (LXD) container?

Tags: gui, gpu, lxd, headless

In its great post https://blog.simos.info/how-to-easily-run-graphics-accelerated-gui-apps-in-lxd-containers-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/ Simos Xenitellis describes how to run GUI apps inside the container.

What I need is to run several apps (`chromium-browser`) that uses a GPU for acceleration in the *headless* server.

Is it possible? How? What X server should I use?

I cross-posted this question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/568664/17765

Answer (score 0):

There is an updated guide that simplifies the process, 
https://blog.simos.info/running-x11-software-in-lxd-containers/

Both guides expose the hardware acceleration of the host to the container. Therefore, you should be able to run chromium-browser with GPU acceleration, as if you were running on the host.

To verify that the container is setup correctly, try to run the following. If both run successfully, then GPU acceleration has been setup correctly in the container.

```
glxinfo
glxgears
```